# In NODE.JS, the newline code (%0A) will decode back to what character?

Tags: javascript, url-encoding, urldecode

I have a pretty simple question, but a few simple googling and stachexchange queries were not able to answer it, so i guess i'm missing something here.

Here are my simplified parameters:

1. I'm using Javascript.
2. I have a text that needs to get URLEncoded and the text have more than 1 line.

My question is: What is the character for newline before the text get encoded? (I know that after the encoding the newline will be encoded into %0A)

I guess asking "What char is decoded when decoding %0A" will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those codes consist of a percent sign, followed by a two character hexadecimal number representing a byte value.

So in this case, the byte value is 0A, representing the ASCII newline character. This is commonly written as `\n` inside strings in JavaScript (and others, like PHP).

But I think your question suggests you want to do some search and replace for this character. I would not do that, since there can be other characters too that need encoding. Instead, use the function [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), which can encode the entire string for you. There is [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) as well, but in your case, I think the first is more appropriate.

This example shows how special characters (newline, space, and others) are encoded to an url-friendly format. Note that the diacritic `é` translates to the two bytes of its UTF-8 representation.

```js
document.write(encodeURIComponent("Normal text\nEéy, check the specials: /, + and \t!"));
```

Comment: I need to do something else. How can i store a string with newline in it?
For example: consider the following text: 
**text in line 1\n text in line2**
How can i save it that `encodeURIComponent` will encode it to **text in line 1%0A text in line2**

Comment: That's exactly what that function does. I've added a sample/

Comment: Decoding it just works the other way. It would translate %0A back to the newline character (ASCII 10). Note that this character isn't *actually* `\n`. `\n` is just a way of embedding that character in a string. Basically that's just another encoding. There is [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) too.

Comment: so what if i would like to store a string that contains newline (before encoding) in a constant? how would i represent the newline so it will be encoded into %A0?

Comment: Then you use `"\n"`. I don't understand what I don't understand. :-s